# Using thread exception and app domain unhandled exception within constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, exception

I have used `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` before but usually I only use this for a single form. So usually I would use the `Main` in `Program.cs`.

```
try {
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) => .Handle(sender, (Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
    Application.ThreadException += (sender, e) => ExceptionHandler.Handle(sender, e.Exception);
    Application.Run(ApplicationBase);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Handled Exception");
}
```

In my new situation however I have a host of forms for my current project with a single base form that the other forms inherit from.

What I am trying to do is handle exceptions that are thrown in a derived form within code from the base form - I plonked the above code into my base's constructor hoping I could do it that way but when there is an exception, it doesn't hit the event.

Any reason why I can't do this in the constructor and any alternatives?

**NOTE:** I previously asked this in `Vb.net` instead of `C#` so deleted my previous question and refactored my code so I could have a `C#` answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those events are global events; they have nothing to do with individual forms.

You can keep your current code in `Main()` and it will work fine with multiple forms.  (unless you have multiple UI threads)

Comment: But you need to call `Applicaiton.Run(Form)`  and I have multiple forms which could be run potentially - so I wanted to handle it within the Base form for the many forms that could potentially be run.

Comment: @LukeHennerley: These are **global** events.  They apply to **all** code running on the UI thread.